# Customizing marker titles in google maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Given that googlemap markers can be customized, is it possible to customize the markers' titles as well?

I mean to change the appearance of the marker title, instead of just displaying some plain old text in it using *marker.setTitle()*.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need to make a custom info window:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows